# Stellung von Adverbien in den Sätzen

Tags: sentence-structure

> Wir kommen gleich/sofort auf diese Frage zurück

oder

> Wir kommen auf diese Frage gleich/sofort zurück

Die gleiche Frage zum Wort "dabei":

> Wo warst du dabei mit deinen Gedanken?

oder

> Wo warst du mit deinen Gedanken dabei?

Hängt es von bestimmten Wörtern ab oder gibt es eine generelle Regel?

Ich habe im Internet herausgefunden, dass Dat. immer vor Akk. während Adverbien, die Zeit oder Ort beschreiben (wie z.B." jetzt" oder "gleich"),  immer nach einem Verb stehen müssen. Stimmt das?

Answer (score 7):

Die Stellung von Adverbien in einem deutschen Satz ist wesentlich flexibler, als einen das manche Sprachkurse glauben machen wollen.

Es gibt viele mögliche Positionen, die einen Satz entsprechend markieren (d.h., mit denen man eine bestimmte Betonung setzt), sowie in den meisten Fällen eine Standardposition, die man verwendet, wenn man keine besondere Markierung setzen will.

1. Prinzipiell können Adverbien am Satzanfang stehen:

   > Sofort kommen wir auf diese Frage zurück

   Ist das der Fall, müssen Subjekt und Verb ihren Platz tauschen, damit das Verb, wie im Deutschen üblich, Position 2 einnehmen kann.
2. Adverbien stehen *normalerweise* (also nicht "immer") vor einem Akkusativ-Objekt, aber hinter einem Dativ-Objekt.

   > Unser Metzger legt seinen Kunden gerne mal ein paar Gramm mehr drauf.

   Dieser Satz mit der Standard-Adverbialposition kann aber durchaus auch umformuliert werden zu

   > Unser Metzger legt gerne mal seinen Kunden ein paar Gramm mehr drauf.

   Diese Position markiert das "gerne mal" und hebt es hervor. Diese spezielle "Regel" ist sehr weich. Ich habe ein bißchen mit mir gekämpft, ob ich sie in die Antwort aufnehmen soll, weil sie kaum eingehalten wird.
3. Adverbien stehen **nie** direkt vor Pronomen

   > <s>Unser Metzger legt gerne mal ihm ein paar Gramm mehr drauf</s>
   >
   > Unser Metzger legt ihm gerne mal ein paar Gramm mehr drauf

   Sind sowohl Dativ- als auch Akkusativ-Objekt Pronomen, rutscht das Adverb ganz nach hinten:

   > Unser Metzger legt es ihm gerne mal drauf.

Die üblicherweise postulierte Regel "Zeit, Grund, Ort, Art und Weise" der Reihenfolge von adverbialen Bestimmungen *untereinander* stellt auch nur einen Anhaltspunkt dar, der von vielen realen Sätzen durchbrochen werden kann:

> Gestern sind wir wegen Nebels auf der Autobahn nur sehr langsam gefahren.
>
> Gestern sind wir auf der Autobahn wegen Nebels nur sehr langsam gefahren.
>
> Wir sind gestern wegen Nebels auf der Autobahn nur sehr langsam gefahren.

Das sind die prinzipiellen Regeln für die Position von Adverbien im Satz. Ausser diesen gibt es noch eine ganze Menge Mögichkeiten, wenn noch andere Satzglieder dazukommen.